# Crear un audio a partir de 2 arreglos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola tengo una imagen png, leo este archivo y extraigo la información de los 3 vectores de la matriz. En 2 vectores tengo información de audio, quisiera saber como puedo crear un wav file con estos 2 vectores de audio.

```
import wave
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img=mpimg.imread('imagen.png')
imgR = img[:,:,0]
imgG = img[:,:,1]
imgB = img[:,:,2]
```

Estuve buscando pero no tengo idea como crear el audio con la libreria wave, utilice el comando wave.write pero me genera error

Comment: Cuál error te genera?

Comment: Me dice que el wave.write no existe en la libreria

Comment: intenta instalando `PyWave` en lugar de `wave`. https://pypi.org/project/PyWave/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería `scipy`. Te quedo un ejemplo de como se haría con un conjunto de datos random:

```
#Importo librerías
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

#Genero unos datos aleatorios, en tu caso, por las dos matrices.
data = np.random.uniform(-1,1,10500)

#Con la fuunción Writte, pongo el archivo a crear, el rate (número de datos) y el conjunto de datos.
write('test.wav', 10500, data)
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la ayuda.